# Cassandra: Unknown/dynamic filters on a table, like a "feed" of tweets from an unbounded number of people

Tags: twitter, cassandra, filtering, denormalization

I get/understand the concept of creating tables to satisfy a specific query.

But, what about queries that are dynamic?

Let's say I create a "tweet" table. I follow two users, Paul and Jim. Surely, there isn't a "tweets_by_paul_and_jim" table. So what do I do?

Do I query the results for each user query, and combine them into a sorted list for each request, AT request time? This really won't work because a user could follow 30,000+ (unbounded) number of people.

How does twitter solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you tweet a message, it's ending up in each of your followers timeline. Twitter will simply write the message to each timeline using a fanout approach. You can read more about how this used to work back a few years ago in [this article](http://highscalability.com/blog/2013/7/8/the-architecture-twitter-uses-to-deal-with-150m-active-users.html).

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot.